# Which ticker code to buy when the company has two different tickers? (e.g., VACQ & VACQU)

Tags: stocks

So I saw *Vector Acquisition* in the news recently. I was investigating if they would be worth investing in.

However I found it was listed under two different tickers `VACQ` & `VACQU`. They seem to be listed on the same exchange and are not (as far as I can tell) like `BRK.A` and `BRK.B` e.g., different sized share slices and or different voting rights.

In the case of `VACQ` & `VACQU` they both have a similar price but not exactly (give or take a few cents).

The only difference I could find was one was called *Vector Acquisition* and the other *Vector Acquisition Unit*

I have also seen this with other companies like LVMH.

So lets say I do decide to buy some shares in say *Vector Acquisition* (or whatever).

**How do I work out the difference between the different tickers and decide which of the two (or more), is the best one for me to buy?**

Answer (score 1):

When Vector Acquisition did its IPO, they issued a unit (VACQU) which consists of one common share (VACQ) and one-third of a warrant, exercisable at $11.50 (VACQW).

If you divide the price of a warrant by 3 and add that to the price of the common, the total should be close to the price of the unit.